# jquery ui sortable trashbin show and hide on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a html table that is sortable by using jquery ui. I then added a tablerow that acts as trash can. For esthetic reasons I only want the trashcan visible when a user is dragging a table row. I do this by creating the table row on the active event and I remove the table row the deactivate event. However I noticed that it does no longer remove the item when it's being dragged in the trashbin. I tried to fix this by using a settimeout so that there is a delay before the tablerow dissapears however this is not working.

I would also like to know I can fix it, and how to make it drop down instead of instantly popping in([Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14379660/Animation.mov)), and move back up instead of disappearing(reverse of example).

I have a [JSfiddle setup here](http://jsfiddle.net/4qxp63rn/) also here is the html for the table:

```
<table class="table" id="tableDevices">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Protocol</th>
        <th>Systemcode</th>
        <th>Unitcode</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody class="ui-sortable">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;"></tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">BBQ</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">pollin</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">31</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">4</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">off</td>
        <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span></td></tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">Server</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">pollin</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">15</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">1</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">off</td>
        <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span></td></tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">Kitchen</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">pollin</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">31</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">1</td>
        <td class="AllowEdit" contenteditable="true">off</td>
        <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the javascript I'm running

```
//Code to drag and drop order table
    var fixHelperModified = function (e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function (index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return $helper;
    };

    $("#tableDevices tbody").sortable({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableDevices > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td colspan="6" id="trash" class="trash">Trash</td></tr>');
        }
    }, {
        deactivate: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#trash").remove();
            }, 500);
        }
    }, {cancel: '[contenteditable]'}, {connectWith: '#trash'}, {helper: fixHelperModified});


    $("#trash").droppable({
        accept: "#tableDevices tr",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the event triggering I think. Because you remove and add the element every time you would have to bind the event every time too. You can prevent this by just adding the element inline and then just change the css properties.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qxp63rn/2/)**

**JS**

```
$("#tableDevices tbody").sortable({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $('#trash').css('display', 'table-row');
    }
}, {
deactivate: function (event, ui) {
        $("#trash").css('display', 'none');
}
```

**CSS**

```
#trash {
   display: none;
}
```

**HTML** (first row of tbody)

```
<tr id="trash"><td colspan="6" class="trash">Trash</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeateadly creating and deleting the element, just hide and show it. Add the row to the HTML of the table, hide it when the page loads, and then use this

```
activate: function (event, ui) {
            $('#trash').show();
}
```

and this

```
deactivate: function (event, ui) {
            $("#trash").hide();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txj2onyr/).

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't seem to be working.